# Next and Previous buttons are not working properly

Tags: list-manipulation, dynamic, button

I really need some professional help here! :)

I have 2 buttons. They are working, but I am using a list and whenever there is a duplication in the list (same word) the button does not work properly (as the system does not realize that the second word is a different word, so that everything gets switched back to the first word).

Example:

```
list = {"time", "Snow", "mother", "queen", "stepmother", "magic", "day", "queen", "huntsman"}
```

I have a duplication of the word "queen" in the list. So that, when I am just on the second "queen" and I click "Next", I'll get "stepmother" and not "huntsman" because of the duplication of the word in the list.

Code:

```
 DynamicModule[{},

        Column[{

        InputField[Dynamic[f], String, MenuList -> list, 
         Alignment -> {Left, Center}], 

    Button["Previous", 
     Dynamic[f = 
       list[[Max@{Position[list, f][[1, 1]] + 1, 
          Length@list}]]], Alignment -> {Right, Center}, 
     ImageSize -> Automatic],

    Button["Next", 
     Dynamic[f = 
       list[[Min@{Position[list, f][[1, 1]] + 1, 
          Length@list}]]], Alignment -> {Right, Center}, 
     ImageSize -> Automatic]

    }]]
```

Do you know any solution for this problem?

Thank you very much,

Fanni

Answer (score 1):

I think the following code solves your problem:

```
list={"time","Snow","mother","queen","stepmother","magic","day","queen","huntsman"};
f=list[[1]];
{Button["Previous", 
  list=RotateRight[list]; f=list[[1]]],
Button["Next", 
  list=RotateLeft[list]; f=list[[1]]]}
Dynamic[f]
```

Answer (score 1):

Some form of index is required.  However it needs to not show in the `MenuList`.  Using `Interpretation` does the trick.  The input field can still be used to type in the input.

```
list = {"time", "Snow", "mother", "queen", "stepmother",
   "magic", "day", "queen", "huntsman"};

list2 = MapIndexed[Interpretation[#1, {First[#2], #1}] &, list];


DynamicModule[{},
 Column[
  {InputField[Dynamic[f,
     ({i, f} = If[StringQ[#], {0, #}, Last[#]]) &],
    String, MenuList -> list2, Alignment -> {Left, Center}],

   Button["Previous", If[i == 0,
     cases = Cases[Last /@ list2, {_, f}];
     If[cases != {},
      i = Max[1, cases[[1, 1]] - 1];
      f = Cases[Last /@ list2, {i, _}][[1, 2]]],
     i = Max[1, i - 1];
     f = Cases[Last /@ list2, {i, _}][[1, 2]]],
    Alignment -> {Right, Center}, ImageSize -> Automatic],

   Button["Next", If[i == 0,
     cases = Cases[Last /@ list2, {_, f}];
     If[cases != {},
      i = Min[Length[list2], cases[[1, 1]] + 1];
      f = Cases[Last /@ list2, {i, _}][[1, 2]]],
     i = Min[Length[list2], i + 1];
     f = Cases[Last /@ list2, {i, _}][[1, 2]]],
    Alignment -> {Right, Center}, ImageSize -> Automatic]

   }]]
```

[image]